# What is the n of Markov chain exactly equal to?

Tags: probability, markov-process

Section 7.2 of the book "transition probability graph" coming from the book "Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition by Dimitri P. Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsiklis" gives some explanation of the notion of revisiting a state precise.

[image]

Let's apply this to this sunny rainy example (not included in that book).

Let the initial state $i$ be sunny.

Let A(i) = {sunny, rainy} be the set of states that are accessible from i.

Let the weather chain be the sequence (sunny, sunny, sunny, sunny, rainy, rainy, rainy, sunny, sunny, sunny, sunny, rainy, rainy, sunny, sunny, sunny), which has 16 elements, illustrated by this figure.

[image]

The first transition $(i,i_1) = (sunny, sunny)$

The last transition $(i_{n-1},j) = (sunny, sunny)$

In this particular case, is the n equal to 15, **no matter the initial state is or not probabilistic**?

Is n the length of the Markov chain?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, n is just the number of steps between states taken. In your example, n is 15.

Comment: n is just the number of steps between states taken, **no matter the initial state is or not probabilistic**, right?

Comment: Yes, as I said above.

Comment: Would you please provide an authoritative textbook or open source implementation as a reference?